# Выводить страницу оплаты в iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма с данными, которая автоматически при нажатии кнопки `submit` отправляется на сайт `robokassa` (в `action` у формы стоит ссылка на страницу оплаты). Как я могу страницу оплаты выводить в `iframe`, а не в новой вкладке браузера?

Comment: у формы есть атрибут target, может его надо установить равным имени (name) ифрейма?

Comment: @Sergey, спасибо, думаю, это верный путь. только почему-то браузер не хочет выводить в `iframe`: `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://auth.robokassa.ru... does not permit cross-origin framing`...

Comment: Форма по какому адресу и куда показывает action? Разные домены?

Comment: @Sergey, форма на одном сайте, а ссылка в `action` - на страницу оплаты платежной системы.

Comment: Значит https://auth.robokassa.ru защищается от ваших манипуляций фреймами https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options